# Why isn't $\phi (t) = \dfrac{1}{a-t},\,\, t \in X \equiv (-\infty, a) \cup (a, +\infty)$ a solution to $y' = y^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, connectedness

Why isn't $\phi (t) = \dfrac{1}{a-t},\,\, t \in X \equiv (-\infty, a) \cup (a, +\infty)$ a solution to $y' = y^2$? $\phi_1 (t) = \dfrac{1}{a-t}, \,t \in (-\infty, a)$ and $\phi_2(t) = \dfrac{1}{a-t}, \, t \in (a, +\infty)$ are solutions according to the book, but not $\phi (t)$ and the reason is that $X$ is not connected. But I can't understand why. Any hints?

Comment: I assume that is the definition in that book.

Answer (score 1):

One good reason to say $\phi(t)=\frac{1}{a-t}$ isn't the solution is because it's not the most general solution on a disconnected domain. We can extend,

$$\phi_1(t)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{a_1-t} & t < a_1 \\ 0 & t > a_1\end{cases}$$
$$\phi_2(t)=\begin{cases} 0 & t < a_2 \\ \frac{1}{a_2-t} & t > a_2\end{cases}$$

Then we can construct the more general solution when $a_1 \le a_2$ and $C_i \in \{0,1\}$: $\phi(t)=C_1\phi_1(t)+C_2\phi_2(t)$ which is valid on the domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{a_1, a_2\}$.